# How to attach POST variables to socket.io connection?

Tags: android, node.js, sockets

I have a webchat application which is running on Node.js and Socket.io. After user logins on main homepage port 80, he gets redirected to port 3000 (chat application) along with POST data containing his ID, username etc... On chat application page it validates details and registers user as new client.

However, now I am building android chat application and I get immediately disconnected from chat because basically android client fails validation since there is no POST data attached.

How can I add POST data along with connection request?

Here is a code that does it all in android:

```
try {
    IO.Options opts = new IO.Options();
    opts.forceNew = true;

    final Socket socket = IO.socket("http://host:3000", opts);
    socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener(){
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args){
            socket.emit("mobile_ping", sf.getTextValue(MainActivity.this, R.id.editText));
        }
    });

    socket.connect();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("ERR", String.valueOf(e));
}
```

Comment: Socket.io operates primarily over websockets (when they are available). While the initiation for websockets looks like http headers, it is not http and you can't have any post body or variables. I think you either need to recheck how your setup works or rethink your approach.

Comment: @Hargobind my Socket server accepts headers from incoming clients, on website PHP does that, but I need to find way to do that on mobile client.

Comment: Headers are quite different from post data, you should update your question to reflect that.